# Drawing part of a texture on a triangle in openGL

Tags: opengl, geometry, drawing, textures

I'm trying to draw part of a texture on a triangle. The triangle is defined by 3 points. One of the points will always be the center of the image. Now I want to draw a part of the texture on that triangle. So the triangle would cut out that part of the image and draw it on itself. But I don't want the texture to scale when drawn. It has to stay the same. So even if the triangle's base points fall outside of the image. The image can't be scaled. I don't understand how this can be done. Whenever I play around with texturing, the image gets scaled or drawn multiple times it seems.

Here is an image: so the red triangle would be drawn exactly like that in openGL.

[image]

Comment: Fixed-function or programmable pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

In your fragment shader check the `s` & `t` values on your texcoord and `discard` if either is less than zero or greater than one.

**EDIT:** Example:

```
// g++ main.cpp -o main -lglut -lGLEW
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void CheckStatus( GLuint obj )
{
    GLint status = GL_FALSE, len = 10;
    if( glIsShader(obj) )   glGetShaderiv( obj, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status );
    if( glIsProgram(obj) )  glGetProgramiv( obj, GL_LINK_STATUS, &status );
    if( status == GL_TRUE ) return;
    if( glIsShader(obj) )   glGetShaderiv( obj, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &len );
    if( glIsProgram(obj) )  glGetProgramiv( obj, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &len );
    vector< char > log( len, 'X' );
    if( glIsShader(obj) )   glGetShaderInfoLog( obj, len, NULL, &log[0] );
    if( glIsProgram(obj) )  glGetProgramInfoLog( obj, len, NULL, &log[0] );
    cerr << &log[0] << endl;
    exit( -1 );
}

GLuint LoadShader( GLenum type, const char* src )
{
    GLuint shader = glCreateShader( type );
    glShaderSource( shader, 1, &src, NULL );
    glCompileShader( shader );
    CheckStatus( shader );
    return shader;
}

GLuint LoadProgram( const char* vert, const char* geom, const char* frag )
{
    GLuint program = glCreateProgram();
    if( vert ) glAttachShader( program, LoadShader( GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vert ) );
    if( geom ) glAttachShader( program, LoadShader( GL_GEOMETRY_SHADER, geom ) );
    if( frag ) glAttachShader( program, LoadShader( GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, frag ) );
    glLinkProgram( program );
    CheckStatus( program );
    return program;
}

#define GLSL(version, shader) "#version " #version "\n" #shader

const GLchar* vert = GLSL
(
    120,
    void main()
    {
        gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_MultiTexCoord0;
        gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
    }
);

const GLchar* frag = GLSL
(
    120,
    uniform sampler2D texture;
    void main()
    {
        if( any( lessThan( gl_TexCoord[0].st, vec2( 0.0, 0.0 ) ) ) || 
            any( greaterThan( gl_TexCoord[0].st, vec2( 1.0, 1.0 ) ) ) )
        {
            gl_FragColor = vec4( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );
            //discard;
        }
        else
        {
            gl_FragColor = texture2D( texture, gl_TexCoord[0].st );
        }
    }
);

GLuint prog = 0;
GLuint tex = 0;
void init()
{
    prog = LoadProgram( vert, NULL, frag );

    unsigned char bits[ 32 * 32 * 4 ];
    for( unsigned int i = 0; i < 32*32; ++i )
    {
        bits[i*4 + 0] = rand() % 255;
        bits[i*4 + 1] = rand() % 255;
        bits[i*4 + 2] = rand() % 255;
        bits[i*4 + 3] = 255;
    }

    glGenTextures( 1, &tex );
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex );
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST );
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST ); 
    glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 4, 32, 32, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bits );
}

void display()
{
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glLoadIdentity();
    double w = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH );
    double h = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT );
    double ar = w / h;
    glOrtho( -3 * ar, 3 * ar, -3, 3, -1, 1);

    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity();

    glUseProgram( prog );
    glUniform1i( glGetUniformLocation( prog, "texture" ), 0 );    
    glActiveTexture( GL_TEXTURE0 );
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex );

    glBegin( GL_TRIANGLES );
    glTexCoord2f( 0.5, 0.5 );
    glVertex2f( 0, 0 );
    glTexCoord2f( 1.5, 0.5 );
    glVertex2f( 2, 0 );
    glTexCoord2f( 0.5, 1.5 );
    glVertex2f( 0, 2 );
    glEnd();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit( &argc, argv );
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE );
    glutInitWindowSize( 640,480 );
    glutCreateWindow( "test" );
    glutDisplayFunc( display );
    glewInit();
    init();
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think I understand what to do. The u and v values correspond to texcoord[0].st[0] and texcoord[0].st[1] in my fragment shader? To make my triangle I first bind the texture and then call glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
Then I set the texcoord like this for example for every point.
where p2x and p2y are calculated. 
glTexCoord2f(p2x,p2y);
glVertex2f(l.p2.x,l.p2.y);

But is this the right way to do stuff or am I completely wrong and if I'm wrong can you maybe direct me to a good tutorial on this.

Comment: @DavidMaes: Edited in an example.  Sorry for the gratuitous mix-n-match of deprecated functionality.

Comment: And yeah, after reviewing the GLSL spec I should have said `s` & `t` instead of `u` & `v`.  Edited.

Comment: Ow ok I'm getting closer. I just still don't understand how to calculate gltextcoord2f. I have multiple triangle that have 1 point in the center of the images. the other 2 points change constantly and can fall out or inside the image. I calculate the coord by taking the difference in distance from the center to the other points. Then dividing that distance by the width and height of the image. So giving me a value that will be between 0 and 1 if the point falls inside the image. Or so I think. But triangles still stretch the image.